# AsRef<Path> vs &Path

Tags: rust, types, type-mismatch

I have the following struct:

```rust
struct Config<'a> {
    path1: &'a dyn AsRef<Path>,
    path2: HashMap<SomeEnum, &'a dyn AsRef<Path>>,
}
```

Then when I try to create a new instance of this config:

```rust
Config {
    path1: &Path::new("path/to/file1"),
    path2: HashMap::from([(SomeEnum::Value, &Path::new("path/to/file2"))
}
```

I get no errors for the variable of `path1`, but for `path2` I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
expected trait object `dyn AsRef`, found `&Path` 
Note: expected struct `HashMap<_, &dyn AsRef<Path>>` 
found struct `HashMap<_, &&Path>`
```

I don't get why this works for `path1`, but not for `path2`.

Comment: btw `&'a dyn AsRef<Path>` seems a bit weird - why not just store `&'a Path` instead? `impl AsRef<Path>` is useful when you want to have a nice API that accepts. When _storing_ those objects, though, you should just use `Path` or `PathBuf`, depending on whether you want a borrowed or an owned value. (If in doubt, go with `PathBuf`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference isn't quite able to figure out what's supposed to happen here.  It isn't able to see that the `&&Path` reference should be converted to `&dyn AsRef<Path>`.

You need to help it figure out that the second tuple slot should be `&dyn AsRef<Path>`.  You could do this with a cast:

```
Config {
    path1: &Path::new("path/to/file1"),
    path2: HashMap::from([(SomeEnum::Value, &Path::new("path/to/file2") as &dyn AsRef<Path>)]),
}
```

You could also create the tuple first with a type annotation:

```
let v: (SomeEnum, &dyn AsRef<Path>) = (SomeEnum::Value, &Path::new("path/to/file2"));
    
Config {
    path1: &Path::new("path/to/file1"),
    path2: HashMap::from([v]),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like in this case, the compiler won't automatically cast the reference into a trait object reference. But you can do it manually with `as`:

```rust
    Config {
        path1: &Path::new("path/to/file1"),
        path2: HashMap::from([(SomeEnum::Value, &Path::new("path/to/file2") as &dyn AsRef<Path>)]),
    }
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fa8c6a8f90a4ac109d1cb10930e50593)